# SQL varchar to bit error

Tags: sql, bit, varchar

Okay, I'm getting this error when I try to execute this procedure. The thing is I'm not trying to convert to a bit at any time. At least not on purpose. I'm a bit stumped at the moment.

```
Declare @AValue varchar(max)
set @AValue = (SELECT Value 
        FROM dbo.Tbl 
        WHERE Name=@FILE 
            AND Value LIKE (CAST(@MODID as varchar(15))+'|%'))
set @AValue = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@AValue, '|', '.'), 1) -- Hack way to parse.

INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl
(
    Name, 
    Value, 
    Type, 
    CDT, 
    UDT, 
    Active, 
    User
)
VALUES 
(
    'Agreement', 
    (CAST(@MODID AS varchar(15)) + '|' + @AValue), 
    'Download', 
    GETDATE(), 
    GETDATE(), 
    1, 
    @USER
)
```

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: The actual error message would be immensely valuable as well.

Comment: @marc_s due to `CAST` and `GETDATE` I'm guessing SS

Comment: @JNK: yeah, my guess, too - but I'd like to **know** from the OP ....

Comment: It would help if you posted the entire procedure, so we can see the parameters and their types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer. I came back today and the error I was getting was completely different than the one I had when I first asked the question. Sorry I forgot to write that error.

Problem was my WHERE clause was getting multiple returns from the database cause I had been testing a lot, so there were duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

Check the triggers on the tables, particularly the insert.  Lots of times unexplainable errors can lurk there.

Answer (score 0):

Post the error, the CREATE PROCEDURE statement, and - most importantly - the call to the procedure that is failing. Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Most likely, the stored proc has a parameter of type BIT, and you are calling the procedure with a value like 'F', '-1' or some other string that can't be converted to BIT.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: I don't think so. "the stored proc has a parameter of type BIT, and you are calling the procedure with a value like 'F', '-1' or some other string that can't be converted to BIT." is appropriate as an answer than as a comment. It may be wrong, of course, but it's not a comment.

Answer (score -3):

GetDate needs to be assigned to something in T-SQL before it can be used in a insert.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @CDT DateTime
DECLARE @UDT DateTime
SELECT @CDT = GetDate()
SELECT @UDT = GetDate()

INSERT INTO dbo.Tbl 
( 
    [Name],  
    [Value],  
    [Type],  
    CDT,  
    UDT,  
    Active,  
    User 
) 
VALUES  
( 
    'Agreement',  
    (CAST(@MODID AS varchar(15)) + '|' + @AValue),  
    'Download',  
    @CDT,  
    @UDT,  
    1,  
    @USER 
)
```